# ZFS backup with rotating offline drives

Tags: backup, zfs

I am currently in the process of setting up a decent home NAS. The main concern is integrity of the data and I therefore decided on using ZFS as a filesystem. Unfortunately this does put some requirements (or recommendations to be more precise) on the hardware that make it a rather expensive solution. This prohibits me from implementing an off-site backup on a similar system and I am therefore looking for an alternative solution.

Ideally, I would have three removable hard drives of which one would sit near the server and be connected weekly or so. The others would remain off-site and they'll be rotated every now and then. I am aware that this poses a risk to new data, but I'm planning to back this up in an alternate way.

The question is what I should put on the removable drives. Initially I thought of putting a `zpool` on each and using `zpool send` and `zpool recv` to update them, like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/927753/would-a-zfs-mirror-with-one-drive-mostly-offline-work). I do however think that it is quite possible that the drives are "damaged" once I need to put back the backup and I would like ZFS to take care of that. Ideally all three removable drives would be in a mirror configuration up to two drive swaps ago, which will allow ZFS to use all of them to fix problems in the old data when restoring the backup. The drives will however never be connected at the same time, so this might not be possible. Does ZFS provide a means to implement what I am after, or should I use a different method?

Answer (score 3):

> Unfortunately this does put some requirements (or recommendations to be more precise) on the hardware that make it a rather expensive solution. This prohibits me from implementing an off-site backup on a similar system and I am therefore looking for an alternative solution.

I don't know your exact hardware and performance needs, but be advised that decent systems can be quite cheap if you know what you are looking for and can accept some slight downsides. Specifically:

- The amount of needed RAM you find online is vastly overstated, because RAM is cheap compared to dozens of disks, and RAM is critical for performance (as it is used for the ARC and deduplication). If you only need to saturate a 1 Gbps ethernet link (~110 MB/s) and have mostly streaming workload (meaning disk instead of RAM is accessed constantly), 4 to 8 GB of memory are sufficient (even 2 GB might still work).
- Enterprise disks with 7200 rpm, SAS connectors, low error count and 200 MB/s throughput are nice, but also not really needed. Two lowly 5200 rpm consumer drives can saturate your ethernet without problems. Random reads will be slower, but you don't have hundreds of clients that want to access different files each second either.
- An HBA from LSI with 8 SAS ports is a reliable choice, but can be pricey. Most hardware SATA ports on server boards are from Intel and also quite reliable. They also consume less power. Again, speed does not matter here, as you do not have SSDs or use multipathing or extenders.
- CPU power is nearly meaningless, all current server CPUs have plenty of power. Some dual-core Celerons in the 30€ range also support ECC memory, aside from that you can use low-power Atom SoCs or low-power dualcores or quadcores from AMD. Those boards also frequently already have 6 SATA ports and a PCIe for later extension, as well as support for 16 to 64 GB of memory, at about 300€ including CPU, memory, and power supply.
- Aside from that, there are some SoHo server offerings from large companies like Dell or HP, where you can get a full server for 300€ (economies of scale), including case, disk and warranty. The expansion options are limited, but 4 to 6 disks are still plenty.
- Finally, if you live somewhere where power is cheap, you may look at used enterprise hardware. Those systems are fast, durable, and cheap, but also loud and power-hungry. You have to calculate if the trade-off is worth it.

---

> I do however think that it is quite possible that the drives are "damaged" once I need to put back the backup and I would like ZFS to take care of that. Ideally all three removable drives would be in a mirror configuration up to two drive swaps ago, which will allow ZFS to use all of them to fix problems in the old data when restoring the backup.

In my eyes it is very unlikely that your live system with at least a two-way mirror and three offsite disks die at the same time. If one of the backups is still usable, you would have only lost the data of a week, which is much less severe (and can be mitigated by e.g. differential online backup of only newly modified files).

But assuming it will happen, let's compare all possible backup configurations (each time assuming your live system has 2 disks as mirrors and all 5 disks are of equal size):

### 3 independent disks, send/recv is used to sync data to 3 pools

- The disks cannot correct bit errors, but they can detect them and you may restore files from the other disks
- As they are independent, you can keep them at three locations and have 3 different backups (concerning user errors, software bugs)
- Handling is simple, as each disk/pool is treated in the same way

### 3 disks as mirrors, send/recv is used to sync data to 1 pool

- Essentially a complete offline system with very good resiliency
- On the other hand you have all you eggs in one basket (theft/fire)

### 3 disks as degraded mirrors like described in the linked question

- See the linked answer for up- and downsides
- You also have only one version

---

So, in summary: It depends what is more critical to your needs - multiple independent points in time, or a single one that is more resilient against failure.

If you go for the second solution, be sure to also enable regular data snapshots to guard against things like encryption malware (which would be mitigated somewhat by having multiple disks). Also, be sure to still distribute the three disks and store them in different places to guard against fire/theft/loss.

Comment: The server would not have to do anything big for now, but I would like the option of expanding in the future. Services like Plex and VPN are appealing. If I use the three external drives as three independent pools I would be able to discover errors, but would I be able to correct them at the block level using another device? If I understand correctly, the other option would be to just copy the file, but this will break snapshots.

Comment: You would only detect them and get a list of damaged/unreadable files (files where some blocks are damaged within). Then you would take another disk and simply copy over the files in question. This assumes that you have many small files (not only a single large VM image), and that not all of your files change all the time. Essentially, you have a small window of vulnerability for the files that have been changed since the last week (old stuff is already on the other disks).

Comment: If I understand correctly, copy-on-write means that new blocks are allocated when a file is changed. Old blocks will remain part of snapshots if relevant. Extrapolating from this I would think copying a file over from one of the backup drives would create a new block and make the filesystem reference that. Snapshots would still be pointing to the old block, which in fact has not been fixed, just replaced. Effectively, this would mean the file can be recovered using this method, but any snapshots would be lost forever. Am I missing something here or is it impossible to actually fix the block?

Comment: @Octaviour Although I have never tested this specific case (blocks of snapshot damaged that are not shared with live version), I would assume it is as you say. Although you would most likely have the snapshots also on the second disk, stitching them together is difficult/impossible because of the read-only and all-or-nothing behavior of snapshots. If you desire perfect snapshot safety, this approach may not be for you. But to be fair, the window for this to happen is pretty small, and most people use snapshots as a way against accidental deletion, so they are destroyed regularly anyway.